# ng-class binding in kendo menu

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-ng-class

i'm trying to bind a CSS class to a button of a kendo menu :
Here is my code for the menu :

```
               {
                    id: "button_grille_tri",
                    type: "splitButton",
                    menuButtons : $scope.liste_recherche,
                    click: function(e){
                        $scope.rechercheColonnes(e);
                    }
                },
```

it's a part of the menu which works.

Here is the instanciation of the liste_recherche variable :

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.siagridColumns.length;i++){
  $scope.liste_recherche.push({ 
    cssClass : "champ_recherche",
    attributes: {"ng-class": "{'tick_recherche':tickActivation("+"'"+$scope.siagridColumns[i].id+ "'"+ ")}"} ,
    text : $scope.siagridColumns[i].header, id : $scope.siagridColumns[i].id });
        }
```

tickActivation is a function that return a boolean :

```
    $scope.tickActivation = function(id){
        return $scope.etats[id];
    };
```

i have tried several things :
1) if i replace ng-class by class, the class is working but not dynamically
2) i put the ng-class into the text part with the good format, and it didnt worked no matter the quotes issues, i tried all the possibilities
3) even if i replace tickActivation(...) by true it doesnt work. 
4) i have put a $scope.$apply into another :

```
    $scope.rechercheColonnes = function(e){
        if ($scope.colonnesTri.length == $scope.siagridColumns.length){
            $scope.colonnesTri =[];
        }
        var compteur = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<$scope.colonnesTri.length;i++){
            if ($scope.colonnesTri[i] == e.id)
                compteur++;
        }
        if(compteur == 0){
            $scope.colonnesTri.push(e.id);
        }
        $scope.etats[e.id] = true;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
```

and with that $apply, i can see that tickActivation is used on each click on the menu, with the good argument and a fine return. But there is no binding and the ng-class doesnt work... i havent find any answers on any documentation / community.
At least, thank you for reading the post, i hope someone will find the solution.